# mongodb config broken, find query too slow every 10 min

Tags: mongodb, config

We use 2Shard 3Replication Mongodb 2.6.3

ReplicaSet 1 (Primary1-1[config], Secondary1-2[config], Secondary1-3[config])
ReplicaSet 2 (Primary2-1, Secondary2-2, Secondary2-3)

When Secondary1-3 is shutdown, every 10min find,findandmodify query too slow
but, mongodb profile slow query not saved.

so, config server moved primary2-1 and start-up.

query performance has been normalized.
(our query per second, 500qps over)

so every 10 min, does mongo config lock for synking other node?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not entirely clear on your issue from the current problem description: it sounds like you are shutting down one of your config servers and seeing some effect on queries? Can you edit the description with steps to reproduce and better details on the problem observed? What is the order of servers in your `configdb` string for `mongos`? As a first step I would upgrade from 2.6.3 (a very early release in the 2.6 series: June 2014) to the last 2.6.x release (2.6.12: March 2016) as there were a number of significant improvements.

Comment: MongoDB 2.6 reached end of life in Oct, 2016 so ideally you should also plan to upgrade to an actively supported release series (currently MongoDB 3.2 or newer). Note: the "Sync Cluster Connection Configuration (SCCC)" config server topology used in MongoDB 2.6 was deprecated in MongoDB 3.2 and replaced with [Config Servers as Replica Set (CSRS)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-config-servers-to-replica-set) in MongoDB 3.4 and newer. CSRS builds on MongoDB's standard replica set protocol and improves consistency and availability of config servers.